# Spring Data JPA example fail with user lacks privilege [PUBLIC.AUDITABLE_USER]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The example is from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa)

jpa\example\src\test\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="jpa.sample.plain">
        <class>example.springdata.jpa.simple.User</class>   
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:spring" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" /> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I still see the issue after versions in jpa\pom.xml were updated and look like:

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: table (`AUDITABLE_USER`) doesn't exist for some class of yours (`User`)?

Comment: Thank you!  I will delve further into the Spring-Projects and https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ Guide to figure out where the table should be constructed.